# Handling API and UI errors in flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, error-handling

I'm working on a Flask app that will serve as my website and my API.

For example, all routes which have the `/api/*` pattern are in the API category and other routes are for my website.

Since all API routes return a `jsonify` as a result and the website is a graphical user interface, I want to handle errors in the proper way.
I mean if they are calling an API and it ends in an exception I want to exception return a `jsonify` for the error handling and if they are on my website the error should be returned as a rendered HTML.

I'm open to any suggestion on how to implement this except the following answer:

```
Using another IP, domain, port or etc...
```

Edit: I like to use the following code

```py
@app.errorhandler(exceptions.HTTPException)
def error(exception: exceptions.HTTPException):
    * magic *
```

Comment: You could just return `jsonify({'success': False}), 400` in your route and it should return that JSON with the output you want to give about the error and with the code in this example `400`. I think that way would just be complicating things. This is the process I follow when my API fails I just return that and the error code.

Comment: @DeadSec I currently return the result in the error handler and API has no problem but when someone for example goes to `/aboout/` which is a misspell and return 404 will get a jsonify result and it is not user friendly.

Comment: So you want to make a custom 404? Something like that?

Comment: @DeadSec I have that too. The problem is if I want to show that it will mess up API and if I want to return jsonify it is not user friendly for errors in web

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was simple... At the time I posted this question I was not familiar with blueprints and now I do.

With blueprints I can handle errors in blueprints, I just had to separate the API section and UI section into 2 blueprints and deal with the exceptions on jsonify or UI Error